# Send Windows Phone Push Notifications using WebJobs & nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, push-notification, windows-phone, azure-webjobs

I am currently using nodejs and a scheduled webjob to query a website and save some data to a json file for further consumption in a native Windows Phone app.
Now I'd like to add a feature where I can notify the users if new data was found on the website using push notifications.
Unfortunately I have not found any info on how one might do this or if that is even possible atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The https://github.com/tjanczuk/wns Node.js module serves this exact purpose.